# Is it possible to gather all the params from an ActivatedRoute in angular?

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

I'm creating and angular 4 application. It happens that I need to obtain parameters from my URL which are at different depth levels causing that it's not uniform the way in which I can obtain my params.

Suppose we have this URL:

```
https://mysite/companies/:companyID/cups/:cupId/drawings/:drawId
```

Usually, according to the angular docs, we would need to do something like:

```
ngOnInit() {
this.activatedRoute.parent.parent.params.subscribe((params: Params) => 
{this.companyId = params['companyId'];
});
this.activatedRoute.parent.params.subscribe((params: Params) => 
{this.cupId = params['cupId'];
});
this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params: Params) => 
{this.drawId = params['drawId'];
});
}
```

Note that this is considering we are inside the DrawDetailComponent, meaning we are in a component which is the last child on this hierarchy.

Also please note that depending on how deep you are in this hierarchy, you will need to add|subtract .parent to your activatedRoute to be in the correct position where you can successfully get the params you are looking for.

So, is it possible to have all the parameters from your urls with the same call?

Something like:

```
this.activatedRoute.parent.parent.params.subscribe((params: Params) => 
    {this.companyId = params['companyId'];
    {this.cupId = params['cupId'];
    {this.drawId = params['drawId'];
});
```

We would like to have a uniform, not depth dependent way for retrieving all the parameters from our URL.

Actually we also tried something like:

```
const property = 'companyId';
this.activatedRoute.pathFromRoot.forEach((item) => {
  if (item.snapshot.params.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
    item.params.subscribe((params: ParamMap) => {
      this.companyId = params[property];
    });
  }
});
```

But we hope to find a better, more generic, testable way.

Usually, in frameworks like Django, the developer is able to gather all the information needed from the url in one single step. It's ok having subscriptions to automatically handle changes on those parameters in the case of Angular but IMHO it's far from being comfortable + testable.

Comment: Iterating through parents is all you can do here. You're fighting the framework, the router isn't supposed to be used like that. Angular isn't Django. The devs learned a tough lesson from A1 router. A4 router was designed to be highly modular, consider this a special case of encapsulation. Child routes should be unaware of parents and receive all the stuff they need through `data`, own params and common providers. You probably have XY problem with app design that is supposed to be solved another way.

Comment: Thanks, interesting answer, it's pointing me in another direction, probably a more appropriate one. Could you please share some links describing this mentioned XY problem? 

On the other hand, suppose we have 4 components, A, B, C, D, each one nested inside the previous one: A -> B -> C -> D and you need in C, to have data coming from the 3 parent components. Should it be correct sharing that data by using @Inputs inside of each one of the components? D component will end up having 3 inputs, only to have access to simple parameters coming from the parents.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* you should be able to do something like this:

```
this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
    this.companyId = params['companyId'];
    this.cupId = params['cupId'];
    this.drawId = params['drawId'];
});
```

I have had luck with something similar to this in my applications. Notice that I am not going up to the parent. The activated route should have all you need.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I agree. I say this knowing there are exceptions. But I always cringe just a little bit when when people want "loose" routing functionality. There are definitely use cases for dynamic routing but not too many where you're nesting dynamic on top of dynamic. Out of the whole app your routing should be the most predictable and consistent in terms of operating as designed.

Comment: @R. Richards, this is not working for us. Please notice we have nested routes here. Let say you have a module, in this case, CompanyModule, which has a child module: CupModule, each one of those has their own routing. When you ask for the activatedRoute from inside of a any component in the CupModule, it doesn't knows about the parent module routes. That's why in the example we have 3 different levels of .parent nested requests, depending on the  depth.

Comment: @joshrathke, usually in frameworks like Django I would simply have all the parameters any time when needed with one simple call. I think this is not a completely mature feature in Angular. Maybe having some answers to this question I will change my mind :)